# Cleaning up a timeline I'm trying to create in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have written a query that looks like this:

```
    SELECT
id,
product_name,
CASE WHEN by_month = 'January 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END AS january_2018,
CASE WHEN by_month = 'February 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END AS february_2018,
CASE WHEN by_month = 'March 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END AS march_2018,
CASE WHEN by_month = 'April 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END AS april_2018
FROM (
SELECT
mnth,
id,
product_name,
CASE WHEN mnth = '2018-01-01' THEN 'January 2018' 
WHEN mnth = '2018-02-01' THEN 'February 2018' 
WHEN mnth = '2018-03-01' THEN 'March 2018' 
WHEN mnth = '2018-04-01' THEN 'April 2018' END AS by_month,
SUM(sales) total_sales
FROM (
SELECT
date_trunc('month', event_date) mnth,
id,
product_name,
SUM(sales) sales
FROM
table1
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-04-30'
1,2,3)
WHERE sales > 0 
GROUP BY 
1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY 
1,2, by_month, total_sales
```

But this produces a very fragmented result that looks like this

```
id   product_name january_2018 february_2018 march_2018 april 2018
123  abc               500           0           0          0
123  abc               0             700         0          0
123  abc               0             0         900          0
123  abc               0             0           0         100
```

What I would like is to eliminate the '0' results (I'm aware that's what I intentionally put in the `ELSE` statement but I needed a placeholder.

I would like the results to look like this.

```
id   product_name january_2018 february_2018 march_2018 april 2018
123  abc               500          700         900         100
```

How can this be accomplished? Would it be something in the `ELSE` statement or another subquery on top of it? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT id, product_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN by_month = 'January 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS january_2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN by_month = 'February 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS february_2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN by_month = 'March 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS march_2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN by_month = 'April 2018' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS april_2018
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id, product_name
```

Comment: Oh... duh. Not sure why this slipped me.

Answer (score 0):

For a cleaner aggregation, you could use FILTER clause with aggregate functions like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  product_name,
  SUM(total_sales) FILTER (WHERE by_month = 'January 2018') AS january_2018,
  SUM(total_sales) FILTER (WHERE by_month = 'February 2018') AS february_2018,
  SUM(total_sales) FILTER (WHERE by_month = 'March 2018') AS march_2018,
  SUM(total_sales) FILTER (WHERE by_month = 'April 2018') AS april_2018
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  id,
  product_name
```

It's a SQL:2003 standard feature, but currently supported on PostgreSQL only. For more info, see [The FILTER clause: Selective Aggregates](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter)